# Only way to bevel is export and reimport model?

Tags: bevel

Bevel has no effect on a simple model, unless I export it to STL and re-import it. The imported version is identical, but works fine with bevel.

The original and imported file are treated with Limited Dissolve

Why is this happening, and how can I bevel the original without this weird workaround?

Below: Left is the bevel-proof geometry, the tool does nothing. Middle is the re-imported .stl, right is the Limited Dissolve'd imported .stl that can be beveled.

[image]

Comment: OK, photo added

Comment: It's hard to tell from just the image, but it looks like the left most image has edge splits in it. Select everything by hitting A, then hit M > By Distance to remove doubles, and try beveling it then. But that's just a guess. You would need to upload the file for me to be sure.

Comment: Again, please show the topology of the object ( the actual vertices and faces in edit mode) to understand better

Comment: Rekov- that fixed it, thanks!